# How to add user to have super user permission

Tags: linux, sudo, opensuse

I am using `OpenSuse linux 12.3` version & i have created new user called `jenkinsadmin`. with this account i am unable to create a folder/file inside `/usr`, `/opt`, `/var` locations .

To enable `sudo` permission i have modified below in the `/etc/sudoers` file., however could not worked.

Method-1

```
##
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
jenkinsadmin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Method-2

```
## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

`usermod -aG wheel jenkinsadmin`

still getting the below error

```
/opt> touch filetest
touch: cannot touch ‘filetest’: Permission denied
```

Need help to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

Adding user to sudoers means that user is allowed to use command `sudo`.

```
$ sudo touch /opt/filetest
[sudo] password for jenkinsadmin:
```

Enter your (jenkinsadmin's) password and the command will be done as superuser.

```
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for jenkinsadmin:
```

And after supplying the password you would have a root's shell.

Comment: This works, I would need to create files/directories inside /opt with jenkinsadmin user.